# Ansible: docker related command doesn't work inside playbook, but does work once run directly

Tags: bash, postgresql, docker, ansible

I have following task in my playbook:

```
- name: install pg_stat_statements extension in the postgres container
  shell: docker exec octopus_postgres_{{ group_id }} /bin/bash -c 'psql -h localhost -U postgres -p 5433 -c "CREATE EXTENSION pg_stat_statements;"' #  && service postgres restart')"
  async: 10
  poll: 0
```

Once I run the playbook this task seems to successfully finished, but if I check the postgres database - there are no changes to it. The task didn't actually worked.

If I run the above mentioned command manually on the host via bash, everything works fine and the databased gets updated, like this:

```
docker exec octopus_postgres_iaa /bin/bash -c 'psql -h localhost -U postgres -p 5433 -c "CREATE EXTENSION pg_stat_statements;"'
```

While trying to check what is wrong with the task, I tried the following:

```
- name: install pg_stat_statements extension in the postgres container
  shell: docker exec octopus_postgres_{{ group_id }} /bin/bash -c 'touch /1 && psql -h localhost -U postgres -p 5433 -c "CREATE EXTENSION pg_stat_statements;" && touch /2' #  && service postgres restart')"
  async: 10
  poll: 0
```

I've noticed that file `/1` indeed has been created inside of the container, but the file `/2` hasn't...

What is wrong with the command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `docker exec` at all isn't right here.  In general you want to avoid it for tasks like this: if the container gets deleted and recreated, any local setup you've done with `docker exec` will be lost.  When you're trying to make a change to some sort of server using its API, you usually just call its API, instead of getting a root shell on the server host and then doing things, but this latter step is what `docker exec` does.

The [standard `postgres` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) supports putting SQL fragments in a container-side `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` directory, which will get processed the very first time the container is started (only).  A very typical use is to mount a host-system directory with initialization scripts on to that directory.  In Ansible this might look like:

```
- name: create pg_stat_statements extension file
  copy:
    dest: /docker/postgres/initdb/create-stat-statements.sql
    content: |-
      CREATE EXTENSION pg_stat_statements;

- name: start postgres container
  docker_container:
    image: 'postgres:11'
    name: octopus_postgres_{{ group_id }}
    published_ports: ['5433:5432']
    volumes:
      - '/docker/postgres/initdb:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d'
      - '/docker/postgres/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
```

Alternatively, you can manage the database like any other PostgreSQL database (local, cloud-hosted, remote, ...) using Ansible's built-in tools; in this case, the [`postgresql_ext`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/postgresql_ext_module.html#postgresql-ext-module) module for creating extensions.

```
- name: enable pg_stat_statements PostgreSQL extension
  postgresql_ext:
    name: pg_stat_statements
    port: 5433
```

In terms of your original statement, there are probably two things going on.  First of all, if you do use the `docker exec` path to interact with a container, you always need to use the port the server thinks it's running on and not any remapped ports from the `docker run -p` option or equivalents: in your statement you need to use the default port 5432 and not 5433.  Secondly, since you run the task with `async: 10, poll: 0`, Ansible launches the task and immediately moves on to the next one, without ever checking to see whether it succeeds (see [Asynchronous Actions and Polling](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_async.html)), so you don't actually know whether or not the `docker exec` task succeeded.  My guess is that nothing is happening because it's failing to connect to the database, but you never see this error.